# Regular expression to Match if string A appears before String B on a Page using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a generated HTML page where I expect string "A" to appear before String "B" on the page. (Note that A and B can be in different lines on the Page with arbitrary strings / characters in between.

I am trying to create a regular expression that checks for this criteria.

Here is what I have

```
regexp = Regexp.new ".*#{S1}.*#{s2}"
match = page.body ~= regexp
```

where S1 and S2 are strings "A" and "B" respectively.

after executing this on a page with A appearing before B match still returns nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
match = /.*#{S1}.*#{S2}/m =~ page.body
```

**Edit (by Dennis Mathews, 2012-03-16):** The first .* was not required .. so the working code is

```
match = /#{S1}.*#{S2}/m =~ page.body
```

Comment: Super - That does it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks was able to get rid of the first .* (a lot less heat now)

Comment: This does not work. If there is another s2 in front of this match it will still match.

Comment: @MrNagoo: I agree with your second sentence, but (obviously) not with your first. (I guess you're taking "I expect string 'A' to appear before String 'B' on the page" to mean that 'A' must appear before the *first* occurrence of 'B'? That's a plausible interpretation, but it doesn't seem to be what the OP had in mind.)

Answer (score 4):

Why use regex at all? Just use string index comparisons:

```
first = page.body.index(S1) or return false
second = page.body.index(S2, first) or return false
return true
```